# How to share a gruntfile.js file or grunt tasks between multiple projects?

Tags: gruntjs

My team currently works on multiple projects which all have their own *gruntfile.js* file. But they're all about the same, copied-pasted on every new project... Which is not good at all !

I'm searching for a way to maintain only one *gruntfile.js* and share an up-to-date version between all the projects. I see two ways of doing this : deploy the shared gruntfile.js to some path accessible through our internal network and ...

- ... use `grunt --gruntfile = /path/to/share/gruntfile.js taskName` on every call to a grunt task inside any project directory. A Jenkins build could keep the shared file up-to-date, re-deploying it on commit. In this way, a project wouldn't have its own *gruntfile.js* file anymore.
- ... inside the proper *gruntfile.js* of every project, find a way to tell grunt to import everything (tasks, configInit, etc.) declared in the shared *gruntfile.js*. Like it would be done with Maven pom.xml files having a parent pom.

Does anyone see a reason why one or both solutions wouldn't work ?

Does anyone know a simple way of doing this, maybe using an existing tool or plugin ?

**Edit**: We're on SVN, not GIT.

Comment: Why not have one grunt file and have the build task take in a parameter, the parameter being what directory to build? and then check it into source and you're good.

Comment: I would probably go with the second approach, it seems to be the most extensible and portable idea.

Comment: @still_learning : it's the solution I prefer too. But it's the one I don't know how to do. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found a way to share tasks declaration over multiple projects : I created a custom grunt plugin. This plugin contains :

```
custom-grunt-plugin
|_ config
    |_ config.js : contains all the tasks configurations
|_ tasks
    |_ custom-grunt.js : contains all the tasks declarations
|_ package.json : package info
|_ README.md : package documentation
```

I published my plugin and added it as a devDependency of all my projects.

Finally, the grunfile.js of all my projects :

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

  // Load custom tasks
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('custom-grunt-plugin');

  // Load grunt tasks automatically
  require('load-grunt-tasks')( grunt );

  // Load configuration from the custom grunt plugin
  var config = require('custom-grunt-plugin/config/config');

  // Add project specific variables to the config
  config.pkg = grunt.file.readJSON('package.json');
  config.paths = {
    app: 'app',
    dist: 'dist/<%= pkg.name %>/<%= pkg.version %>'
  };      

  grunt.initConfig( config );

};
```

That's all ! Probably not the best solution. But this one works.

The next step would be to transfer the list of dependencies from the package.json of the projects to the package.json of the custom plugin, and install all dependencies recursively with 'npm install'. But it seems npm can't load and install the dependencies of the dependencies...